# A scalable lock-free channel

Tags: concurrency, go, lock-free

Here's my lock-free channel impl [lfchan](https://github.com/OneOfOne/lfchan/),

I didn't want to copy/paste the code here since it is multiple files.

I'm trying to get an idea of what can be improved or if there are any bugs in it.

### chan.go

```
type innerChan struct {
    q       []aValue
    sendIdx uint32
    recvIdx uint32
    slen    uint32
    rlen    uint32
    die     uint32
}

// Chan is a lock free channel that supports concurrent channel operations.
type Chan struct {
    *innerChan
}

// New returns a new channel with the buffer set to 1
func New() Chan {
    return NewSize(1)
}

// NewSize creates a buffered channel, with minimum length of 1
func NewSize(sz int) Chan {
    if sz < 1 {
        panic("sz < 1")
    }
    return Chan{&innerChan{
        q:       make([]aValue, sz),
        sendIdx: ^uint32(0),
        recvIdx: ^uint32(0),
    }}
}

// Send adds v to the buffer of the channel and returns true, if the channel is closed it returns false
func (ch Chan) Send(v interface{}, block bool) bool {
    if !block && ch.Len() == ch.Cap() {
        return false
    }
    ln, cnt := uint32(len(ch.q)), uint32(0)
    for !ch.Closed() {
        if ch.Len() == ch.Cap() {
            if !block {
                return false
            }
            runtime.Gosched()
            continue
        }
        i := atomic.AddUint32(&ch.sendIdx, 1)
        if ch.q[i%ln].CompareAndSwapIfNil(v) {
            atomic.AddUint32(&ch.slen, 1)
            return true
        }
        if block {
            if i%250 == 0 {
                pause(1)
            }
        } else if cnt++; cnt == ln {
            break
        }
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
    return false
}

// Recv blocks until a value is available and returns v, true, or if the channel is closed and
// the buffer is empty, it will return nil, false
func (ch Chan) Recv(block bool) (interface{}, bool) {
    if !block && ch.Len() == 0 { // fast path
        return nilValue, false
    }
    ln, cnt := uint32(len(ch.q)), uint32(0)
    for !ch.Closed() || ch.Len() > 0 {
        if ch.Len() == 0 {
            if !block {
                return nilValue, false
            }
            runtime.Gosched()
            continue
        }
        i := atomic.AddUint32(&ch.recvIdx, 1)
        if v, ok := ch.q[i%ln].SwapWithNil(); ok {
            atomic.AddUint32(&ch.rlen, 1)
            return v, true
        }
        if block {
            if i%250 == 0 {
                pause(1)
            }
        } else if cnt++; cnt == ln {
            break
        }
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
    return nilValue, false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Out of order bug

It appears that there could be a case where the items inserted into the channel can be read out of order.  From reading your test code,  it seems that you want to maintain a FIFO ordering, so I am guessing this is unwanted behavior.  Here's the sequence of events that can trigger the behavior:

1. Initially, `sendIdx` `recvIdx` are -1, and `slen` `rlen` are 0.
2. Thread 1 calls `Send`, and atomically increments `sendIdx` to 0.
3. Thread 1 is context switched out before filling in `q[0]`.
4. Thread 2 calls `Send`, and atomically increments `sendIdx` to 1.
5. Thread 2 fills in `ch.q[1]` and atomically increments `slen` to 1.
6. Thread 3 calls `Recv`, and sees that there is 1 element in the queue because `slen - rlen = 1`.
7. Thread 3 atomically increments `recvIdx` to 0.
8. Thread 3 tries to do a read from `q[0]` but finds that it was empty.
9. Thread 3 atomically increments `recvIdx` to 1.
10. Thread 3 reads from `q[1]` and find the value placed there by Thread 2.
11. Thread 1 wakes up an inserts its element into `q[0]`.

So at this point, the item added by Thread 2 in `q[1]` was read before the item added by Thread 1 in `q[0]`, but it could be argued that Thread 2 inserted its element timewise before Thread 1 so that behavior might be OK.  However:

12. Thread 1 calls `Send` again, and inserts an element into `q[2]`.
13. Thread 3 calls `Recv` and reads the element from `q[2]`.
14. Thread 3 calls `Recv` and reads the element from `q[0]` (after wrapping around the queue once).

Now, it is clear that Thread 1 sent `q[0]` before `q[2]`, but Thread 3 received `q[2]` before `q[0]`, which is out of order.

Comment: recvIdx/sendIdx are initalized to ^uint32(0) which is uint(0) - 1, so the first call either Send or Recv would set them to 0 not 1.

Comment: @OneOfOne Ok I fixed the answer to reflect that.  But the out of order problem remains.

Comment: I see it, although I can't reproduce it, any suggestions?